# Apostrophe won't be saved in database

Tags: database, apostrophe

I'm trying to have a livechat on my website which is working fine so far but as a message is only shown if it's saved in a database I save everything in there right after posting it and read it out to anyone afterwards. But I am not able to save `'` in the database, and if I try escaping the strings it doesn't save anything anymore. The code to save it in the database looks like the following right now:

```
<?php
session_start();
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname', 'user', 'password');

if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['name'])){
    $text = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST["text"]));
    $name = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['name']));
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Berlin");
    $date = date("d.m.Y; h:i:sa");

    if(!empty($text) && !empty($name)){
        $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat VALUES ('','".$name."','".$text."','".$date."')");
        $insert->execute();
        echo "<li class = 'cm'><b>".$date." ".ucwords($name)."</b> - ".$text."</li>";
    }
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using parameters in your prepared statement. It will help with potential SQL injection issues as well as it may solve the apostrophe problem.

Something along the following lines:

```
$stat = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO chat VALUES ('',:name,:text,:date)");
$stat->bindValue(:name, $name);
$stat->bindValue(:text, $text);
$stat->bindValue(:date, $date);
```